# saving iptables rules without logging in to root

Tags: iptables, sudo, root, rules, fedora-22

I am trying to save iptables rules file to /etc/sysconfig/iptables. I want to do this without logging in to root. I tried to using

> sudo iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

but it throws permission denied error.

How can i save the file without logging in to root ? I am using this in my app so i don't want to login to root through the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use sudo, you can do `sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables`

The shell don't have the right to write in /etc/sysconfig/iptables, as it is run in your user.

Answer (score 1):

the standard out redirect is being issued by you not root ... this one-liner works

```
sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 "
```